# Pass JS/CSS from page to template handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Is it possible to pass specific script/stylesheet that are on the page to the template?

Similar to what happens with `{{{body}}}`

Let's suppose that on page X, I need to pass some specific script, which will only be used on page X.

There is something like (illustrative example):

```
{script start}
      <script src="assets/js/customX.min.js"></script>
     <script>
       Bla bla bla bla bla
     <script>
{script end}
```

There in the **template** file, I capture everything that is in the session of the example above.

There is something like (illustrative example):

```
{{script}}
```

### **Image of the structure of what I want to pass to the template.**

[image]

Comment: Would you consider putting the scripts into a Handlebars partial?

Comment: @76484 Could you explain better?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take would be to put the page-specific scripts directly into JavaScript (*.js) files that your page would instruct the browser to download via `<script>` tags.

We could create a `/public` folder out of which to have [Express serve static assets](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). We would need to add `app.use(express.static('public'))` somewhere after our app initialization in order to tell Express which folder is the public one.

We would then put our page-specific scripts - like `accessories.js` into that public folder.

Next, in order to have Handlebars render the path to the corresponding page script, we would add that path to a variable in our `render` call. For example:

```
res.render(
  "accessories",
  {
    pageScriptSrc: "/accessories.js",
  }
);
```

Finally, we would need to add code to our layout file - `pages.handlebars` - to conditionally render the script tag *when* the `pageScriptSrc` variable has a value:

```
{{#if pageScriptSrc}}
    <script src="{{pageScriptSrc}}"></script>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: `Error: if doesn't match pageScriptSrc - 129:11`

Comment: @Tiago: Woops! The closing tag should be `{{/if}}`. I have edited my post.